# Combining pdfs files into one file

Tags: python, vba, pdf

I am trying to automate a one process:
I create a folder on drive. The folder has always a different name. In the folder I have a lot of other folders named by 6 digits, e.g. 111111, 222222, etc.
In each of the  folder are .pdf files named by name of months: January, February...December.

I want to create a tool which goes to each the folder and combine the .pdf files into one file and names by the folder name, e.g. 111111.
What is important, the tool should combine only five .pdfs (from January to May), but always the same.

I would prefer to use VBA if that is possibile. If not, Python would be acceptable as well.
There is no possibility to use any extra paid softwares, such as Nuance PDF or Acrobat.

I use Windows 7. Is there any possibility to use VBA for that?

Comment: So, go ahead! What keeps you from doing what you described? I do not see any [question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) in your post but a list of requirements.

Comment: Hi Storax,
That is not a list of requirements. 

I agree with you. I wrote a discription of a whole process but I do not put my questions. My apologies for that. 
What would be a better choice? VBA or Python? Is there any possibility to do that in VBA?

Answer (score 2):

Please install PyPDF2 python package as follows:

```
pip3 install PyPDF2
```

Assuming you're using Ubuntu System.

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger, PdfFileReader
mergedObject = PdfFileMerger()

fileName=['January','February','March', 'April', 'May'] #5 Months

for fileNumber in fileName:
    mergedObject.append(PdfFileReader(fileNumber+'.pdf', 'rb')) 

mergedObject.write("merged_ouput.pdf")  # Merge the pdfs into a single file.
```

Comment: Thank you. 
I am using Windows 7.

Comment: @Arerox, This will work in Windows 7 also.

Comment: O great. Thank you. I will try to use it.